# Converting to HLS VS MPEGTS

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8, hls.js

I am creating streamable audio by using ffmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -vn -ac 2 -acodec aac -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 -segment_list playlist.m3u8 playlist-%05d.ts
```

My goal was to create content in the HLS format and it seems to work (it is playable by hls.js). I just wonder about the segment_format which is mpegts, is that correct? By reading the answer [here](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-MPEG-TS-and-HLS) mpegts seems to be a different format than HLS. Which is it?

The ffmpeg script above is generating `.ts`-files for the chunks and an `.m3u8`-file for the playlist. Is it possible to play this playlist on all devices that supports `m3u`-playlist? What is the difference between old Winamp-m3u-playlists and the hls format?

Is the `.ts` files still in the same content type as the mp3?

Answer (score 1):

> mpegts seems to be a different format than HLS. Which is it?

It’s both. HLS is not a file type, it a collect of technologies used together to encode and deliver media over Http. One of the technologies is TS

> Is it possible to play this playlist on all devices that supports m3u-playlist?

All devices? Probably not. Nobody can guarantee something to work on all devices. You need to test the devices you care about.

> Is the .ts files still in the same content type as the mp3?

What do you mean by “content type”? Your ffmpeg command has a mp3 an input and a ts wrapped aac stream out. So no, I guess. Unless by content type you mean audio, then yes.

Comment: Thanks! Not really sure but I think that part of the problem with my device is that it cannot determine the format of the .ts files, so it assumes that it is mp3 (a fallback perhaps). Is it possible for the .ts files to contain audio encoded in different formats? Like acc and mp3? How does the device know which format it is?

Comment: Yes, a ts can contain both mp3, and aac. But it is still a ts. If the player can’t read ts, it doesn’t matter what the codec is.  M3u8 can also point to segmentd adts, aac. But if this is just a regular MP3 player, it will probably not play seamless. The device knows the format, because it opens the file and tries to read it.